# Android google maps crashes after fragment navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, android-navigation

I have an app with a navigation drawer and uses fragment to display new screens after user selects a nav item

The part of my MainActivity class that handles that looks like this:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_new) {
            addFragment(new NewFragment(), id);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_start) {
            addFragment(new StartFragment(), id);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_delete) {
            addFragment(new DeleteFragment(), id);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gps) {
            addFragment(new GPSFragment(), id);
        }
...
```

And the `addFragment` method looks like this:

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, int id) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            if (fragmentManager.getFragments() == null) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .commit();
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .addToBackStack(Integer.toString(id))
                        .commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

One of the fragments is a GPS one where I have implemented google maps. It works, but there are 2 major problems with it and I'm not sure what's going on:

1. When I navigate to GPS, then to another fragment, then to GPS (repeated multiple times) using the nav drawer, eventually the screen will turn black and completely reload the MainActivity
2. When I navigate around using the back button (from GPS to another fragment, back to GPS, repeated many times), or use the home button to pause the app and bring it back to resume (repeated multiple times) the app gets extremely slow and takes about a minute to respond to any user input

This must be due to the way I've implemented google maps, or more specifically the way I handle the transition between different states (maybe). I thought that with the way I've implemented my code, whenever I use the nav drawer, or press the back button, or press home to leave the GPS fragment, gmaps will disconnect and the fragment be suspended.

I'm not sure why that would lead to such slowdowns, or a restarting of the app back to the MainActivity. Maybe a memory issue? I'm not sure what would be causing that if I'm always disconnecting from gmaps and removing the fragment when I navigate away. I don't think this was a problem before I added the code to get `mMapView.getMapAsync(this)` working, so maybe its related to the mapready event and how it interacts with navigation?

The GPSfragment simply listens for changes in lat,lon positions and moves the camera and marker to center the users location. Here is the GPSFragment class:

```
public class GPSFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    double lat, lon;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    UiSettings mapSettings;
    CameraPosition cameraPosition;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    Marker marker;
    Location mLastLocation;
    MapView mMapView;

    public GPSFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gps, container, false);

        //Set the nav drawer item highlight
        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        mainActivity.navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_gps);

        //Set actionbar title
        mainActivity.setTitle("GPS");

        //Create api connector and map
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //mMapView.onResume();

        //When map is ready, set it up with a onMapReady callback
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mMapView.onResume();
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            mMapView.onResume();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mMapView.onPause();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mMapView.onDestroy();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mMapView.onLowMemory();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(100); // Update location every second

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            lon = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();

        marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lon));

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lon)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        //Request permission for location data
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //If permission has not been granted
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                //If they have previously declined permission, show explanation
                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, R.string.permission_explain_gps,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(R.string.request_permission, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                0);
                    }
                }).show();
            } else {
                //If no previous declines
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        0);
            }
        } else {
            //If permission has been granted
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMapView) {
        googleMap = mMapView;
        setupMap();
    }

    public void setupMap() {
        mapSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
        mapSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        mapSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mapSettings.setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
        mapSettings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
        mapSettings.setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon));
        marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(lat, lon)).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }
}
```

EDIT: also just noticed that after closing and uninstalling the app from my phone, the map marker icon is still in my status bar at the top, which I think only comes on when the phone is currently requesting location information...